# How to get the resolution of image in iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone

how can I programmatically get resolution of an image in iPhone?

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking at the documentation Apple provide. No problem!

Answer (score 2):

If you load the image into a UIImage, then its size property gives you the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Use image.size.width and image.size.height where image is of type UIImage.